# Swift: Generic Type conform Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, request, protocols

i have some problem with generic type. I want to check if generic type conform some protocol and after pass to another generic function. For example i have function:

```
func requestSignal<T:Mappable>(target:Api) -> SignalProducer<[T], NSError>
```

And i want to do something like this:

```
func request<T>(target:Api, withObjectType type: T.Type) {        
    if let mappableType = type as? Mappable.Type {
        let requestSignal: SignalProducer<[?????], NSError>  = self.requestSignal(target) }
```

But if i tried pass **T** - it doesn't conform Mappable.

if pass **mappableType** - it is not a type

Comment: why don't you just pass in the object instead of the type, then compare `if let mappable = object as? Mappable`

Comment: hmm...i want to create request service which will be know what to do with response json. So it need to know class conform protocol or not.

Comment: so do request(target,withObject:Class.self)

Comment: either that or do 
`func request<T  where T:Mappable>(target:Api)`  I can't remember 100% if this is how you do where,  I know that a where clause can work

Comment: Clear. But how to make T is Mappable and pass into next function?

Comment: Yep, but sometime T will be Mappable (if response is objects) and sometimes not (status code or something like that).

Comment: create 2 function?

Comment: You write 2 methods,  one that handles mappable, and what that doesn't

Comment: Your code becomes cleaner, no need to figure out branching, so better readability

Comment: I do not see other ways.
thx for your answer =)

Comment: did it work?  I am not familiar with protocols so I am learning with you

Comment: Yep, but DRY is crying now somewhere =(

Comment: I dunno what DRY is, sorry

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: what are you using to get it to complain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define T as Mappable, just like you do in the first function.

```
func request<T: Mappable>
```

Comment: Yep, but sometime T will be Mappable (if response is objects) and sometimes not (status code or something like that). And i want to request with one function.

Comment: This works with 2 different methods,  I just tested it in playgrounds, use `func request<T>` for your other types